# Azure Synapse Bulk Load: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am working on [Quickstart: Bulk loading with Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-load-studio-sql-pool) from Azure team. But when I get to step 5 of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-load-studio-sql-pool#steps) section and run the script, I get the following error:

> Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'.

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error, and how can we fix it.

**Remarks**: I created the Synapse workspace, have Storage Blob Data Contributor role on its Data Lake Storage Gen2.

**Error**:
[image]

Comment: You mentioned you have the data contributor role, have you checked *all* the other [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-load-studio-sql-pool#prerequisites)?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks for reading. I created the `Synapse Workspace` using my `Azure AD login`, so I do have Azure AD access to the workspace. But when I run `Grant ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS to 'myAzureADLogin'` on the same dedicated  pool, I get the exact same error `Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'.`

Comment: check this problem reported by someone in [MS forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/aad-auth-error-login-failed-for-user-lt-token-identified/bc-p/1623665/highlight/true#M329) , not sure if it is same reason for you, but good to check that.